# Phase Error with Barrier at Quantum Composer

Tags: quantum-computing, phase

I have created a simple circuit at IBM Quantum Composer.

Diagramm of the circuit:

---

Id  C    Id
H   X    H   (barrier) X

---

quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/files/new?initial=N4IgdghgtgpiBcIBCEBOqCWNUgDQgBMYBnAY0wAcAXDAezARDxAEcJipGB5ABQFEAcgEUAggGUAsgAIATADoADAG4AOmAxhSAGwCuRKStYwtGAEYBGORtKHVYNS1QwA5lJYBtGQF075F1NJ3ABYfNQALN3dzUM0AD0iFL1xI6LsIj1S1UzRMbBSY%2BIyfEABfIA

You see, I have inserted one barrier.

When you delete the barrier you can see a change at the phase disk of the second qubit.
The phase is with barrier pi and without 0.

https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/docs/iqx/visualizations#phase-disk

I think the phase of the second qubit without barrier is right.

I think its an error when the phase changes if the barrier is inserted.

Thank you Christian

Comment: Hi Christian, ask this here if you havent: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/